Difference between a pure and a mixed nash equilibrium
There is a game with 3 agents where each agent invest their effort into 2 tasks. Their efforts add up to 1 and they get rewarded a task based on the effort they put in divided by the total effort. The costs of efforts for each agent and the rewards of tasks are different. Therefore the expected utility for an agent is (probability of getting awarded the task) x (reward of the task) - (cost of effort) x (effort spent on that task). I am trying to find whether a mixed nash equilibrium exists given certain effort cost and task reward values. I am struggling to understand how a mixed nash equilibrium would look like in this context. Would it be a probability distribution over different effort splits? Would it be a mixed nash equilibrium if it converges to a single effort split for each agent with probability 1?

This appears to be a game in which there is a pure strategy of mixed proportions for each individual.
Suppose for a second that a mixed strategy existed in which players chose to send all of their effort into task A with some probability $p$ and into task B with probability $1-p$. Even though one might think that in expectation that is the same as choosing to divide ones energy with $p$% and $(1-p)$%, it isn't. This is because one cannot simply take the average over a binomial distribution like so. Without going into an in-depth proof, just consider the fact that if each player is discretely picking a task then there exists the outcomes, with a non-zero probability, that there is a task in which no player has chosen in which case doing a split of energy is clearly better.
